# Construction of a float array with a size of 520010 is crashing my code after all other sizes are appropriate

Tags: c, memory, scope, size, lifetime

I'm creating a program that tests the runtime of sorting algorithms with various sizes of randomized float numbers. Everything works out fine; the sorting algorithm works, and the execution time is outputted, up to size 520,010, which seems to crash the program.

The program crashes once the float array of size 520,000 is initalized. Is this just too big?

From researching, it doesn't seem like C has a problem with getting rid of memory after an iteration of a loop. So what seems to be the problem here?

```
void readFromFile() {
     FILE *myfile; //File to access randomized floats
     int currentSz = 10; //Size iterator
     int maxSz = 1000010; // Maximum size to reference in the loop

     while (currentSz <= maxSz) {
         // Creates a new array with the current size.
         float fileArr[currentSz]; // PROGRAM CRASHES HERE (at size of 520,010)

         //Initializes file path
         char fileName[200];
         fileName[0] = '\0';
         strcat(fileName, "C:\\Users\\MatthewC\\Documents\\HonorsProject341\\RandomFloats\\");

         // Creates a size string to represent the current array size, and adds sizeStr
         // to the file path.
         char sizeStr[50];
         sprintf(sizeStr, "%d", currentSz);
         strcat(sizeStr, "Floats.txt");
         strcat(fileName, sizeStr);                 

         // Opens the file 
         myfile = fopen(fileName, "r");

         int iterator;

         // Feeds the elements from the file into the created array
         for (iterator = 0; iterator < currentSz; iterator++) 
             fscanf(myfile, "%f", &fileArr[iterator]);

         // Sorts the randomized elements, and times the sorting algorithm.
         clock_t start = clock(), diff;
         heapSort(fileArr, currentSz);
         diff = clock() - start;

         // Converts to milliseconds.
         int millisec = diff * 1000000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

         printf("size: %d runtime: %d\n", currentSz, millisec);
         fclose(myfile);

         // Updates the size.
         currentSz += 20000;
     }
}
```

Comment: float values of 520,000 = 4*520,000 bytes. May not available continuously when you allocate in array. You could try malloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a variable length array in a local variable, which will be (very likely) allocated on the stack. The stack has - compared to the heap - limited size, such that the operation may fail at some point, even if your machine has much more memory available. Try it with `realloc`, which (probably) gives you access to more memory. And check the return value - if it is `NULL`, then the program could not allocate enough memory.

```
 float *fileArr = NULL;
 while (currentSz <= maxSz) {
     char *newFileArr = realloc(fileArr, currentSz * sizeof(float));
     if (!newFileArr) {
        printf("Error allocating %d floats.", currentSz);
        break;
     }
     fileArr = newFileArr;
     ...

 }
 free(fileArr);
```

Comment: Do I free the fileArr after the while loop ends, or at the end of each iteration?

Comment: Edit: this worked! I'm still new to C and memory reallocation, so thanks for the help.

Comment: This code has huge problem. In case `realloc` fails, you have memory leak.